# Is there a way to speed up the following calculation Table[If[TrueQ[],k,Nothing],{k,10^5,10^7}]

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, conditional, number-theory, inequalities

I've the following code:

```
Table[If[TrueQ[2+3^k>2^k+(-1+2^k)*Floor[(3/2)^k]],k,Nothing],{k,10^5,10^7}]
```

Is there a way to speed the calculation up in Mathematica 12.0?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can split the range in 4+ part and use ParallelTable to speed up the calculation

Comment: @Alucard Can you maybe show me how I can do that?

Comment: you don't even need to split the range,the easiest way to you can speed the calculation is  by using ParallelTable in place of Table

Comment: @Alucard If I do that I get an error message: ParallelTable::nopar: No parallel kernels available; proceeding with sequential evaluation.

Comment: i don't know, i don't get any error message, try `$KernelCount` what does mathematica say?

Comment: I don't think you need `TrueQ`

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci tell me ;)

Comment: What do you expect to get out of it? Lots of values of `k` where it holds true, or few? Because it might be easier to pose it as a double problem, using a simpler fast bound to filter out the obvious wrong answers, and then sweep through with the exact search.

Comment: @MikeY no I know that there are a few solutions. But I do not know where to expect them.

Comment: Usually this would work: `Solve[2+3^k>2^k+(-1+2^k)*Floor[(3/2)^k] && 10^5<=k<=10^7, k, Integers]`. In this case, however, `Solve` fails for reasons I don't understand: is it not willing to enumerate the search?

Comment: I'd be surprised to see any solutions. This inequality can be rewritten as `FractionalPart[(3/2)^k] > 1 - ((3/2)^k + 1)/(2^k - 1)`, and for large $k$ the right-hand-side can be approximated as `FractionalPart[(3/2)^k] > 1 - (3/4)^k`. Observing that `FractionalPart[(3/2)^k]` seems to be uniformly distributed on $[0,1)$ (i.e., quasi-random), the likelihood for having a solution $k$ is about $(3/4)^k$ (assuming true randomness); the likelihood for having any solutions $k\ge\kappa$ is about $\sum_{k=\kappa}^{\infty}(3/4)^k=4(3/4)^{\kappa}$, which for $\kappa=10^5$ is *very* small ($10^{-12493}$).

Comment: A good search would be to look for maximum values of `FractionalPart[(3/2)^k]`, and then try that maxima. Is this the problem you are working on? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Unsolved_problem

Comment: Am I missing something? IIRC, this is known to have no solutions for k<4.7*10^8

Comment: The page for the sequence [A240720](http://oeis.org/A240720) on OEIS contains a Mathematica code for record-setters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two functions are each about 30% faster. This first function defines the exponentiations once each.

```
Block[{a, b},
   Table[
      a = 2^k;
      b = 3^k;
      If[2 + b - a - (a - 1)*Quotient[b, a] > 0, k, Nothing],
   {k, 1, 4*10^4}]]
```

The second uses listable properties.

```
Block[{a, b, k = Range[1, 4*10^4]},
   a = 2^k;
   b = 3^k;
   Pick[k, Positive[#]] &[2 + b - a - (a - 1)*Quotient[b, a]]
]
```

Still, a brute force search is, well, brutal...

Comment: Which one of those two is faster?

Comment: Answer edited, but please try each on your machine to answer your comment precisely.

Comment: You can save a bit of time with `Block[{a=1, b=1}, Table[a*=2; b*=3; ...]`.

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the comments, start by reformulating the inequality as

```
FractionalPart[(3/2)^k] > 1 - ((3/2)^k + 1)/(2^k - 1)
```

A brute-force search based on MikeY's suggestion,

```
Block[{p = 1, f = 0, φ},
Do[
   p *= 3/2;                         (* p = (3/2)^k                          *)
   φ = FractionalPart[p];            (* φ = FractionalPart[(3/2)^k]          *)
   If[φ >= f,                        (* new maximum for the fractional part? *)
      If[φ > 1 - (p + 1)/(2^k - 1),  (* success?                             *)
         Sow[k],                     (* yes: emit k                          *)
         f = φ]],                    (* no: update maximum                   *)
   {k, 10^5}] // AbsoluteTiming // First // Reap]
```

still takes on the order of at least a week to get to $10^7$.

I'd be extremely surprised if you find a solution other than $k=1$ and $k=2$.

Answer (score 1):

The Floor make Solve for finding the Zero of the series of values unuseable.

So I suggest a visual path for the solution.

1. Find the lowest zero crossing of the series:

   ListPlot[Table[
     2 + 3^k - (2^k + (-1 + 2^k)*Floor[(3/2)^k]), {k, 1, 6}]]

[image: This suggests that the value for k=3 is closest to zero.]

This suggests that the value for k=3 is closest to zero. It is indeed not zero.

2. From this picture, the trend is clear for great values. For great values the series of numbers diverges to negative infinity. Use the built-in function `Limit` für this purpose.

That is the complete trick Mathematica can do for You.

3. Because this is a visual path of prove for a series behavior I allow another plot:

   ListPlot[Table[
     2 + 3^k - (2^k + (-1 + 2^k)*Floor[(3/2)^k]), {k, 1, 120}], 
    PlotRange -> {{1, 120}, {2, -10^30}}]

[image: The series of values diverges strongly]

I think that is a really great performance improvement and saves plenty of thought of parallelization.

On the other hand this ask questions of how to visualize this best. This is potential divergenz, to the power of k, so plot a log.

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Log10@Abs[2 + 3^k - (2^k + (-1 + 2^k)*Floor[(3/2)^k])], {k, 1, 
   200}]]
```

[image: Polynomial divergence]

To enhance my solution further another plot in logarithm:

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Log10@Abs[2 + 3^k - (2^k + (-1 + 2^k)*Floor[(3/2)^k])], {k, 
   10^5 + 1, 10^5 + 200}]]
```

[image]

This plot starts with the in the question given

> 10^5

. It clearly show traces from the `Floor` function.

A possible reject for my answer is most probable the inequality given is not too correct. That would on the first sight remove the potences from the series.